# How to add a secondary order clause that's a method from a different model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following statement which returns placements in order of the employees' points in the placement model.

```
@placements.includes(:employee).order('points desc')

class Placement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :employee
  attr_accessible :employee_id, :average_score, :points
```

I want to add a secondary order clause but the method is from the employees model and not the placement model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :placements

def total_average_score
 averages = self.placements.pluck(:average_score)
 averages.sum / averages.size.to_f
end
```

So I want to do something like this:

```
@placements.includes(:employee).order('points desc, total_average_score desc)
```

Comment: Why don't you fetch the collection and sort it in the method itself?

Comment: What Bilal meant was you can just fetch for example all Placements (assuming the Model is named Placement) like `placements = Placement.all.to_a` and you can manipulate them like any Array. For example, to order by that Employee function would be `placements.sort_by { |placement| placement.employee.total_average_score }`. Though it's probably also possible with a query, I'm just explaining how to access the collection directly.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. Still learning.